# When validation fails, associated record count still changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Here's a problem.   I have my models:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many    :collection_ownerships
    has_many    :items
    has_many    :users, :through => :collection_ownerships


    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    validates :description, length: { maximum: 100 }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :collection
    has_many :item_ownerships, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_ownerships

    validates :name, :presence => true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :collection, :presence => true

end

class ItemOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :item
    belongs_to  :user

    validates :user, :presence => true
    validates :item, :presence => true
end
```

Here is my controller code:

```
before_filter(:except => :toggle_item_owned_state) do
    @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
end

def new
    @item = @collection.items.new
    @item_ownership = @item.item_ownerships.build(:owned => true, :user => current_user, :item => @item)
end

def create
    @item = @collection.items.new(item_params)
    @item_ownership = @item.item_ownerships.build(:owned => false, :user => current_user, :item => @item)


    if @item.save
        redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem saving this item."
        render "new"
    end
end
```

I have a couple of controller tests:

```
describe 'POST#create' do

            context "with bad data" do
                it "should not create a new record for 'items'" do
                    expect { post :create, :collection_id => batman_collection.id,
                                       :item => { :name => '',
                                                :item_ownership_attributes => { :owned => '1'} }
                            }.to change(Item,:count).by(0) 
                end

                it "should not create new record 'item_ownerships'" do
                    expect { post :create, :collection_id => batman_collection.id,
                   :item => { :name => 'item_name',
                            :item_ownership_attributes => { :owned => '1'} }
                            }.to change(ItemOwnership,:count).by(0) 
                end
            end 
        end
```

When I run my tests, the second one fails:

```
  1) ItemsController authenticated user POST#create with bad data should not create new record 'item_ownerships'
     Failure/Error: expect { post :create, :collection_id => batman_collection.id,
       expected #count to have changed by 0, but was changed by 1
     # ./spec/controllers/items_controller_spec.rb:62:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And ultimately this reflects in the view as well.   Now, when I look in the db, I don't see the record created.   I assume this his happening because somehow Count is reflecting the count of objects in memory, not in the db.

How can I get a handle on the situation.   The problem manifests itself in that when the form is submitted for populating the validation fails for Item, however, multiple instances of ItemOwnership end up showing up on form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  My second test is wrong as it's actually submitting a valid request to the server in that 'name' is not blank.

I removed it and now the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will by default save records created from nested attributes even if the validations of the parent record fails. Thats why `Item.count` increases. `.count` unlike `collection#size` always queries the database.

What you need to do is create a validation on Item that tells Rails that an Item is not valid unless the parent collection is valid.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :collection
    has_many :item_ownerships, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_ownerships

    validates :name, :presence => true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :collection, :presence => true
    validates_associated :collection #! 

end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated

Comment: I appreciate the response but I believe I'm already validating that info.   See my own answer above.  The test was incorrect and fixing it has resolved the problem, although I still can't figure out why my view is incorrect.

Comment: No, you are just validating that there is a item. This does cover the case when you are creating a new record but will still allow child records to be created when updating with invalid params for example.